# Azure DevOps Rest API getWorkItems Not Returning Fields Specified

Tags: javascript, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am new to Azure  DevOps Extensions. Not sure what I am doing wrong here but I cannot get certain fields for work items returned by the `getWorkItems` REST API.

I have tried everything I can find on the message boards and still cannot get certain specified fields to return in the results.

You can see the fields array below to see the specific fields I am trying to get back with the results.

Here are the fields that I can't seem to get returned in the results

```
"Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StartDate"
"Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StoryPoints"
"Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.TargetDate"
"System.AssignedTo"
"Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.CompletedWork"
```

```
     VSS.require(["VSS/Service", "TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient"],
        function (VSS_Service, TFS_Wit_WebApi) {
            // Get the REST client
            var witClient = VSS_Service.getCollectionClient(TFS_Wit_WebApi.WorkItemTrackingHttpClient);

            var fields = ["System.Id", "Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StartDate", "Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StoryPoints", "Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.TargetDate", "System.WorkItemType", "System.Title", "System.AssignedTo", "System.State", "System.Tags", "Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.CompletedWork", "System.Description", "Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.FinishDate"];
            var ids = [workItemID];

            witClient.getWorkItems(ids, fields).then( 
            function(result) {
                document.getElementById("codeblock").innerText = JSON.stringify(result);

            });

        });
```

Here is the JSON that is returned

```
    [{
        "id": 7743,
        "rev": 3,
        "fields": {
            "System.Id": 1234,
            "System.WorkItemType": "Feature",
            "System.State": "Closed",
            "System.Title": "Sprint 39 - Technical"
        },
        "url": "https://<companyurl>/_apis/wit/workItems/1234"
    }]
```

I have even tried the ExpandAll optional parameter in the `getWorkItems` call and those fields are not returned with the results.

i.e:

```
    witClient.getWorkItems(ids, undefined, undefined, ["All"]).then( 
            function(result) {
```

I am stumped, any help or direction on where to look to find these values would be very helpful and appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the integer for the All enum as mentioned on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50284267/10761889)

Comment: I just tried that (thanks for the suggestion) and still get the same results. a bunch of fields are returned, but not the ones I am looking for stated above in the original post, which are part of the work items in Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. In the `vss-extension.json` extension manifest file there is a section for scopes. I had to change the scope from "vso.work" to "vso.work_full" and that did the trick. I am now able to get all the fields for the work items

```
"scopes": ["vso.work"],
```

To

```
"scopes": ["vso.work_full"],
```